# What is the terminal command to set menu bar items and screenshot location in Monterey?

Tags: terminal, command-line, menu-bar, monterey

these commands dont work anymore in mac os 12.x

```
    defaults write com.apple.screencapture location -string "$HOME/Pictures/Screenshots"
    defaults write com.apple.systemuiserver menuExtras -array 
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu"
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Clock.menu" 
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Displays.menu"
    "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Volume.menu"
    killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: Well the Menu Extras stuff wouldn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: does `defaults read com.apple.screencapture` give you anything?

Comment: @MrR it says "{
    "last-analytics-stamp" = "234";
    location = "/Users/username/Pictures/Screenshots";
}"
but for example cmd+shift+4 still saves the screenshot in ~/Desktop

Comment: You can write whatever random text into defaults you like, it doesn't mean the application will honor it.

Comment: hi @Ridhwaan - was wondering if on off chance it gave any value (other than what you'd set) - but it didn't ...  Suspect if you follow the answer then afterwards you can confirm the value is set for last-XXXX

Comment: @MrR It won't be, that's not where the OS keeps it any longer.  (I don't know where it keeps it now)

Answer (score 2):

Launch the screenshot app.  It lives in /Applications/Utilities/Screenshot.

From the Options menu, chose the location you want images to be saved in.

[image]